# Set passed filter to Angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have angular material table and search working ok...

Problem is,
I have `route A` and in this route, I send value to the search box in table in  `route B` and they need automatically set filtered data in a table.

I correctly get this value in the table search box, but it's not applied to the table...if I manually add any letter or number, filter working properly

Here is `component A`

```
goToRouteB(id): void {
  this.router.navigate(["/routeB"], { state: { data: id } }); //id: is some number
}
```

And here is `component B`

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (history.state.data) {   //history.state.data is passed id
    this.searchKey = history.state.data;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
      return data.userId.toString() === filter;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the filter to your dataSource. You only define the filter predicate. Set the filter attribute of your dataSource in `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (history.state.data) {   //history.state.data is passed id
    this.searchKey = history.state.data;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
      return data.userId.toString() === filter;
    };
    this.dataSouce.filter = this.searchKey; // <-- add this
  } 
}
```

Comment: this is correct answer.... but, also it is necessary to convert to string `filter` in return... `return data.userId.toString() === filter.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your logic into `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit()() {
    if (history.state.data) {   //history.state.data is passed id
        this.searchKey = history.state.data;
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean 
        {
            return data.userId.toString() === filter;
        };
     }
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

[As Angular docs says `ngAfterViewInit`:](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views / the view that a directive is in.
>
> Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().

Comment: When move logic to `ngAfterViewInit()` i get this error in console `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: undefined'. Current value: 'model: 7'`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use route params and `@angular/router` provided way of transmitting the data through route params https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero

Comment: thnx, but this does not answer my question. On my way I get data, and I get data to input (search) box, but it is not applied... data is not filtered.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (history.state.data) {   //history.state.data is passed filter values
    this.filterValues = history.state.data;
    this.dataSouce.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues); // <-- add this for multiple filters
  } 
}
```